# Cakephp group by multiple column

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have message table as below 
[image]

In the message listing page i want to show only the last message regarding a particular project/topic that happened between any 2 user.

When i put the group by clause on project_id its showing last conversation of that particular project only.

When i put group by on the all the three column ie project_id,sender_id,receiver_id its showing 2 meesage between any 2 user regarding a project.
My cakephp php code is as below

```
$conditions = array(
    "OR" => array(
        array(
             "Message.sender_id" => $userId
        ), 
        array(
            "Message.receiver_id" => $userId
        )
    ));
$messages = $this->Message->find(
    "all", 
    array(
        "conditions" => $conditions, 
        "order" => array("Message.created" => "DESC"),
        "group" => array(
            "Message.project_id", 
            "Message.sender_id",
            "Message.receiver_id"
        )
   )
);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Can you please show an example of the recorset you would like to get? Also, "_i want to show only the **last** message..._" so I guess you have a column where you store the message datetime.

Comment: I want to show only the last conversation between any 2 users regarding a project.Yes it also have a date time field.